# Salt Stack Installation without yum/internet

Tags: salt-stack, configuration-management

I would like to know if it is possible to install saltstack, for configuration management without internet. The servers doesnt have internet connectivity and i want to install salt master and ~80 servers with minions to manage them.

Anybody gone through the process of installing salt, without internet connectivity. I am unable to find a single RPM which will solve this installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download salt-master and salt-minion  rpm for your os version from below link

https://pkgs.org/download/salt-master

https://pkgs.org/download/salt-minion

rpm -ivh salt-minion*.rpm

rpm -ivh salt-master*.rpm

Answer (score 0):

You can mirror their RPM repo onto a box that is in a DMZ. Your machines behind your DMZ would then reference your mirror and be able to have all the packages required and use Yum to install. This does require you have at least a server with internet you can mirror it with. Another way is if absolutely no internet is available, mirror the repo and then copy the mirror to a flash drive and take it into your closed network and copy it to a server within.